# How do I get my python Webscraper to request the input URL as intended?

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-scraping

I have been trying to follow this basic tutorial for a python webscraper.

https://www.stationx.net/hacking-with-python/?ck_subscriber_id=2408437170

But, unfortunately terminal does not print `"Enter the URL of the blog: "`, nor does it return any scraped `.h2` text if I input a URL.

I have installed `requests` and `bs4`.

No problems are highlighted in VSCode or terminal.

When I run VSCode this is what I get:

```
PS C:\Users\delma\Python\Web Scraper>c:; cd 'c:\Users\delma\Python\Web Scraper'; & 'C:\Users\delma\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\python.exe' 'c:\Users\delma\.vscode\extensions\ms-python.python-2023.20.0\pythonFiles\lib\python\debugpy\adapter/../..\debugpy\launcher' '56485' '--' 'C:\Users\delma\Python\Web Scraper\webscraper.py'
PS C:\Users\delma\Python\Web Scraper>
```

My code:

```
import requests 
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
def scrape_blog(url):
    try:
        response = requests.get(url)
        response.raise_for_status()
    except requests.exceptions.RequestException as e:
        print(f"Failed to retrieve the page: {e}")
        return
    soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'html.parser')
    articles = soup.find_all('h2')
    if articles:
        for article in articles:
            print(article.get_text())
        else:
            print("No article titles found on this page")
    if __name__ == "__main__":
        url = input("Enter the URL of the blog: ")
        scrape_blog(url)
```

Looks like the code in the article. Am I missing something?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  Your ```if __name__ == "__main__":``` block is indented incorrectly.  It should be flushed with the ```def scrape_blog(...):```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just wanted to explain in comments, but I did a bad job.

Your `if __name__ == "__main__":` block shouldn't be indented.

So it should be:

```
import requests 
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
def scrape_blog(url):
    try:
        response = requests.get(url)
        response.raise_for_status()
    except requests.exceptions.RequestException as e:
        print(f"Failed to retrieve the page: {e}")
        return
    soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'html.parser')
    articles = soup.find_all('h2')
    if articles:
        for article in articles:
            print(article.get_text())
        else:
            print("No article titles found on this page")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    url = input("Enter the URL of the blog: ")
    scrape_blog(url)
```

Comment: Thanks @ewokx that certainly does the trick, much appreciated